# Cannot show DropDownList in Google Chrome with encoding characters

Tags: html, asp.net

I am having issue with DropDownList in Asp.net and google Chrome:

In my data sources, I have some values with Encoding characters: `<script>alert('XSS')</script>`

Then I bind it into DropwDownList.
This DropDownList will contain some options after Encoding:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<select>
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="1753">&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt;</option>
        <option value="1758">&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt;</option>
        <option value="1801">&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt;</option>
        <option value="2024">&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt;</option>   
</select>
</body>
```

But this DropDownList cannot open in Google Chrome, I still can open it in FireFox and IE. Where is a wrong points? Can you help me to resolve it?

Comment: Why not? What happens? What do you see in the console?

Comment: Let's try to copy this code and run in chrome and firefox, you will see where is the different things. I don't know why  :'(

Comment: You're right; this is a bug in Chrome. http://crbug.com/496694

Comment: Do u have any solution? I think this is a serious problem. There are too many users are using my system. They can interactive directly this function to bind data to this dropdownlist